# Azure DevOps jobs sequence

Tags: azure-devops

My Azure DevOps pipeline looks pretty standard:

```
trigger:
- ...


variables:
- ...

jobs:
- job: job1
  ...

- job: job2
  ...
```

In logs I see that from time to time `job2` is executed before `job1`:
[image]

but I want to execute `job1` only after `job2`, however `job2` must be executed even in `job1` failed

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to execute job1 only after job2, however job2 must be executed even in job1 failed
>   Is it possible?

By this you mean you want to execute job2 after job1, not the other way around, right?

Yes, this can be done by the `dependsOn` and `condition` attributes of [jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#job).

Please refer to below demo:

```
jobs:
  - job: job1
    steps:
      - script: err
  - job: job2
    dependsOn: job1
    condition: always()
    steps:
      - script: echo this is job2
```

In this demo, job2 will only execute after job1 even job1 failed.

[Check the result of this demo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OT4pN.png)

For more information, you can check [Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops#conditions) and [Specify conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Answer (score 1):

Add the `dependsOn` property

```
jobs:
- job: job1
  ...

- job: job2
  dependsOn: job1
  ...
```